# Pivot a Hierarchy table with no aggregate

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table [**Departments**] with 2 columns:

[**IdDepartment**]

[**IdSubDepartment**]

The table is a kind of hierarchy:

```
IdDepartment | IdSubDepartment

1            | 2

1            | 3

2            | 4

3            | 5
```

If I search for department **5** I want to get the following 5 -> 3 -> 1
(I only need the X level every time - not always the root).

I have written a query that gets a department ID and returns its 3rd level (say I enter ID 5 and get back 1). It works fast and good. the problem is when i do that for 7K departments, it gets stuck.

I want to convert the table to a pivot like this:

```
IdDepartment0 | IdDepartment1 | IdDepartment2 ...

1               2               4

1               3               5
```

**important:** I know the level of each department.
so, when I get department 5, I know it is on level 2 (IdDepartment2)
so I can query my new table in no time and get each department level I want.

How do I do convert to the new table?

thanks in advance
Eran

Comment: perhaps show your attempt....

Comment: What is the primary key in `Departments`?

Comment: my attempt is not worth showing.
As for the PK, there isn't none.
You can use both columns as PK.

Answer (score 0):

This snipped can be expanded to include deeper nesting.

It can propbably be optimized some.

```
;WITH cteLvl AS
(
    SELECT IdDepartment, IdSubDepartment, 0 AS Lvl
    FROM Department 
    WHERE IdDepartment NOT IN (SELECT IdSubDepartment FROM Department WHERE IdSubDepartment IS NOT NULL)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT B.IdDepartment, B.IdSubDepartment, A.Lvl + 1
    FROM cteLvl A
    INNER JOIN Department B ON B.IdDepartment = A.IdSubDepartment       
)
, cteLeaf AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY IdDepartment) AS GroupId
    FROM Department 
    WHERE IdSubDepartment IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT B.IdDepartment, B.IdSubDepartment, A.GroupId
    FROM cteLeaf A
    INNER JOIN Department B ON A.IdDepartment = B.IdSubDepartment   
)
, cteCombined AS
(
    SELECT A.IdDepartment, A.GroupId, B.Lvl FROM cteLeaf A
    INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT IdDepartment, Lvl FROM cteLvl) B ON A.IdDepartment = B.IdDepartment
)

--SELECT * FROM cteCombined

SELECT GroupId, [0] AS Dep0, [1] AS Dep1, [2] AS Dep2, [3] AS Dep3, [4] AS Dep4
FROM 
(SELECT GroupId, Lvl, IdDepartment
FROM cteCombined) P
PIVOT
(
SUM(IdDepartment)
FOR Lvl IN
( [0], [1], [2], [3], [4] )
) AS V
```

Same effect without using the PIVOT construct:

```
SELECT
GroupId,
MAX(CASE Lvl WHEN 0 THEN IdDepartment END) AS Dep0,
MAX(CASE Lvl WHEN 1 THEN IdDepartment END) AS Dep1,
MAX(CASE Lvl WHEN 2 THEN IdDepartment END) AS Dep2,
MAX(CASE Lvl WHEN 3 THEN IdDepartment END) AS Dep3
FROM cteCombined
GROUP BY GroupId
```